# Bootstrap Tagsinput + Typeahead refresh doesn't work

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I have a problem using  bootstrap 3 tagsinput + typeahead component.

I initialize my object using this code:

```
$(".tagsinput-airport[id=arrival]").tagsinput({
                        allowDuplicates: false,
                        freeInput: false,
                        itemValue: 'value',
                        itemText: 'display',
                        maxTags : 1,
                        tagClass: 'tag label label-info tags-airport',
                        typeahead: {
                            items: 'all',
                            afterSelect: function (val) {
                                this.$element.val("");
                            },
                            source: function(query) {
                                return mySource;
                            },
                            updater: function(item) {
                                return item;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Now I need to update the data source dynamically, or better, at some point in the code I created a new object called "newSources" and I want to insert this object as a source instead of the old "mySource".

How can I do? I tried in different ways but without success..

Can any of you help me?

Thank you